Average of $\binom{p}{q}$ over $p\leq q^\epsilon$ for *most* $q$? (unconditionally)
Let $(\cdot/\cdot)$ be the Jacobi symbol. Consider the problem of showing that $(p/q)$ averages to $0$ as $p$ ranges over the primes $\leq q^\epsilon$, or some smaller range. For fixed $q$ (prime or composite), this is known conditionally under the Extended Riemann Hypothesis (using the arguments in Ankeny, 1952, or more recently Lamzouri-Li-Soundararajan, 2015; these actually work for $(\log q)^{2+\epsilon}$ instead of $q^\epsilon$) and hopeless without it. What about an unconditional result valid for almost all $q$?
It seems possible to follow an approach inspired by Linnik (who does existence of $p$ such that $(p/q)=1$, not averages) - while what Linnik did (see, e.g., Thm. 7.16 in Iwaniec-Kowalski) is often seen as a basic application of the large sieve, there is another idea in his proof, independent of the large sieve; that is what generalizes. See below the fold for a sketch.
At the same time, I imagine that this is a question that must have been considered, and I do not want to reinvent the wheel. What is known?

Here is a rough sketch. We will work just with $q$ prime; generalizing the argument to $q$ composite may require some care.
Say that, for every prime $q$ in a set $P$ of primes $\leq N^{1/3}$, the average of $(n/q)$ for $n\leq N^\epsilon$ (or: the average of $(p/q)$ for $p\leq N^\epsilon$ prime) is a bit larger than $0$ (say, $\geq \delta$). Then it should be possible to show that, for a random $n\leq N$ without prime factors $>N^\epsilon$, the expected value of $(n/p)$ for any $p$ in $P$ has to be a bit bigger than $0$ (it's a tiny bias: "bigger than zero" means $\geq \delta'$, where $\delta' =  (2 \delta)^{1/\epsilon}$  or so, I think, at least when the assumption is about the average of $(n/q)$ rather than about the average of $(p/q)$). Then the expected value of $\sum_{p\in P} (n/q)$ is at least $\delta' |P|$; hence, the probability that it is at least $\delta' |P|/2$ is at least $\delta'/2$ (since the maximal value the sum can possibly take is $|P|$). Now, a variance argument should suffice to show that the probability that a random $n\leq N$ has $\sum_{p\in P} (n/q)> \delta' |P|/2$ is $\ll \frac{1}{|\delta'| \sqrt{|P|}}$. Given that numbers without prime factors $>N^\epsilon$ are a positive proportion (depending on $\epsilon$) of all numbers $n\leq N$, we arrive a contradiction as soon as $|P|$ is larger than a (fairly large) constant.
This argument, as sketched, will be weak in at least two ways (the convergence will be very small, and changing $N^\epsilon$ to something smaller will be delicate) and strong in another (the set of bad $q$'s is not just in the minority -- it is bounded). I am not sure of how far it can be stretched.
PS. An alternative approach would be to try to use large-sieve results to derive conclusions on the location of the zeros of $L(s,\chi)$, a bit as in the original proof of Bombieri-Vinogradov. I haven't really looked into that possibility yet; it is bound to be at least somewhat complicated.
